# Как реализовать сохранение в Yii2 Many to many?

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Приветствую всех.
Не понимаю как реализовать в yii2 правильно сохранение через связанную таблицу
Сколько не пытался, получалось только реализовать это через beforesafe и через foreach сохранять по очереди. Должен же быть способ правильнее.

[image: UML]

Интересует правильно ли я описываю модель Новости и как должна работать функция контроллера. Если можно с примером...
Таким способом, добавляется информация только в таблицу News.

**Код функции контроллера**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $news = new News();
    $user = new User();
    $category = Categorynews::find()->all();

    $img = new Img();
    $allnews = new Allnews();
    // выполняет загрузку модели
   // if ($news->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $news->validate() & $user->validate() && $category->validate() && $img->validate()) {
    if ($news->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // Блок загрузки изображения
        $file = UploadedFile::getInstance($img, 'img');   //Get the uploaded file
        $fp = fopen($file->tempName, 'r');
        //$content = fread($fp, filesize($file->tempName));
        $content = file_get_contents($file->tempName);
        fclose($fp);
        $img->img = $content;


    //print_r($user->attributes);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($news);
     // print_r($file);
        echo "</pre>";



        $news->save();
       // return $this->redirect(['index']);
   //     return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $news->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'news' => $news,
            'user' => $user,
            'category' => $category,
            'img' => $img,
            'allnews' => $allnews,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Модель Новости**

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class News extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $current_date;    //текущая дата
    public $queryCategory;   //список категорий
    public $category_list = array();

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['text','title','status','hot_news'], 'required','message' => 'Поле не должно быть пустым'],    //являются обязательными и не должны быть пустыми
            [['created_date', 'updated_date'], 'safe'],
            [['category_list'], 'safe']
        ];
    }


    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => \voskobovich\behaviors\ManyToManyBehavior::className(),
                'relations' => [
                    'category' => 'category_list',
                    'user' => 'user_list',
                    'img' => 'img_list',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    //для определения текущей даты
    public function init(){
        parent::init();
        $this->current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    }


    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%news}}';
    }

    public function getAttributes($names = null, $except = [])
    {
        $attributes = parent::getAttributes($names = null, $except = []);
        return array_replace($attributes, [
            'category_list' => $this->category_list

        ]);
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'text' => 'Text',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'hot_news' => 'Hot News',
            'urlPruf' => 'Url Pruf',
            'created_date' => 'Created Date',
            'updated_date' => 'Updated Date',
        ];
    }


    public function getImg()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(News::className(), ['id' => 'id_img'])
        ->viaTable('work_allnews', ['id_img' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(News::className(), ['id' => 'id_user'])
        ->viaTable('work_allnews', ['id_user' => 'id']);
    }


    public function getCategoryNews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(News::className(), ['id' => 'id_category'])
        ->viaTable('work_allnews', ['id_category' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getNews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(News::className(), ['id' => 'id_news'])
        ->viaTable('work_allnews', ['id_news' => 'id']);
    }


    public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
        if(parent::beforeSave($insert))
        {
            if($this->isNewRecord)
            {

                $this->created_date = $this->updated_date = $this->current_date;
            }
            else
                $this->updated_date = time();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }    

}
```

**Аналогичные модели Картинки, Категории, Пользователи**

```
<?php

namespace backend\models;

use Yii;

class Img extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%img}}';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['img'], 'required'],
            [['img'], 'string'],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'id',
            'img' => 'Img',
        ];
    }

    public function getAllnews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Allnews::className(), ['id_img' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так нормальная практика через **afterSave** сохранять смежные модели. Только оберните в транзакцию, чтоб не нарушать целостность данных в случае ошибки.