# Yii2. Best practice реализации связи many-to-many?

Tags: php, yii2, связи, best-practice

Возникла необходимость реализации связи многие ко многим. Вариантов есть немало. Может есть какой-то best practice по этой задаче? Рассматривал вариант https://github.com/voskobovich/yii2-many-to-many-behavior, но там используют метод установления связей, отличный от появившегося в yii2:

```
link($relationName, relatedModel, $extraColumns = [])
```

Т. е. допустим есть Post и Tag. Есть и PostTag соответственно.
 Я правильно понимаю, что верным решением будет вынести в поведение метод в котором происходит установление связей с помощью `link($relationName, relatedModel, $extraColumns = [])`, обернутый в транзакцию? 
Есть ли пример такой реализации? Я не находил.

Comment: Был похожий вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/562655/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-yii2-many-to-many

Answer (score 0):

1. ссылка с методом, на который Вы ссылаетесь не работает
2. зачем делать поведение? Оно оправдано, если в нем часто используемая функция, в Вашем случае для каждого случая будут свои нюансы. Поэтому сохранение связанных данных более логично реализовать в моделе в событиях afterSave или beforeSave, так же предусмотреть afterDelete и т.д.
3. best practice описаны в документации, то что я предложил в них укладывается, а то что Вы ищите, это странный велосипед. Возможно это будет интересным решением, но уж точно не best practice.